# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle 4,x^2+x+1 \rangle$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle4, x^2+x+1\rangle$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[X]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle $. Since $(\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z)[X]$ is not a PID, irreducibility/reducibility of $x^2+x+1$ is not enough to say whether or not this is a field. My idea is to prove that this ring is not a domain. For example, $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[X]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ is not a domain if $2$ is not in the ideal $\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ but I can't prove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ Let $\,h = x^2\!+\!x\!+\!1.\ $ If $\,2\,$ is a unit: $\,2 f = 1 + 4g + hh'\,$ in $\Bbb Z[x]\,$ $\overset{\bmod 2}\Longrightarrow\,h\mid 1\,$ in $\,\Bbb Z_2[x]\ \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

And if $\,2=0\,$ then  $\,2 = 4g + hh'\,$ so $\,2\mid h'\,$ hence $\,1 = 2g+ h(h'/2)\,$ $\overset{\bmod 2}\Longrightarrow\, h\mid 1\,$ in $\Bbb Z_2[x]\ \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

Comment: Doesn’t our ring plainly contain $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ as a subring? Therefore not a field. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Lubin I did it more directly in case the OP does not yet know the isomorphism theorems etc needed to rigorously deduce that. Presumably if they did then they wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Grudgingly, I must agree.

Comment: @Lubin: It is not so clear. It admits a homomorphism from ${\bf Z}/4{\bf Z}$, but it could be (a priori) not injective.

Comment: I’m sorry @tomasz, I think it is clear: any time $R$ is a ring and you take $S=R[x]/(f(x))$ where $f$ is *monic*, then $S$ is free over $R$ of rank equal to the degree of $f$, and the map $R\to S$ is an injection.

Comment: @Lubin: For you, maybe. But for the OP? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $2$ is in $(x^2+x+1){\bf Z}/4{\bf Z}[x]$ if and only if for some $k\in {\mathbf Z}$ such that $k\equiv 2 \pmod 4$, $k$ is in $(x^2+x+1){\bf Z}[x]$.